# Could not resolve placeholder spring.profiles.active but at the same time profiles are active

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles

I have a Spring boot console application that is launched with multiple active profiles specified in the command line.
The simplified code looks like this:

```
package tmp;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"tmp"})
@Configuration
public class SampleTool implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active[0]}")
    private String firstProfile;

    // Dummy data source just for the sake of starting JPA 
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws ClassNotFoundException{
        DataSourceBuilder dsBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dsBuilder.driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dsBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
        dsBuilder.username("...");
        dsBuilder.password("...");
        return dsBuilder.build();
    }
    public void run(String...args) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleTool.class, args);
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that at execution time, I see the following:

```
2023-02-23 08:34:44.696  INFO 38840 --- [           main] tmp.SampleTool   : The following 2 profiles are active: "local-db", "local-wiki"
```

and yet the application crashes with

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active[0]' in value "${spring.profiles.active[0]}"
```

Why woluld Spring not be injecting the active profiles, if they are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `[0]` is considered a part of the property name because the `${...}` is the property placeholder syntax which can only be used to dereference properties. But you can use [SpEL syntax](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions) to extract the first profile as follows:

```java
@Value("#{'${spring.profiles.active:}'.split(',')[0]}")
private String firstProfile;
```

Since `spring.profiles.active` contains comma-separated profile names, it should be split by a comma before accessing the first element. The `:` is used to define a default value to prevent `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder` exception if no profile is active.

For reference: [Spring Profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#2-using-springactiveprofile)

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't seem to be  the reason. If you just leave ${spring.profiles.active} without the array indexer, it will also fail. Putting a default value merely masks the error, since you can put just about anything in front of a default value and it won´t complain. ${foobar:} also "works"

Comment: Can you share the way you specified active profiles in the command line?

Comment: I was running from IntelliJ, specifying them in the Run configuration. For some reason it has now started working. Not sure what was happening.